# different web app access same couchbase cluster

Tags: couchbase

I have two web apps which need to access different couchbase clusters.
I wonder if the two different web apps(two or more distribute system based web apps) can access a same couchbase cluster?

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course two or more apps can access one cluster. More over many apps can access even one bucket (if it is needed).

I.e. I have one cocuhbase cluster that has 2 couchbase buckets and 1 memcached bucket. Apps that I have: web-site, utility service, mail service, chat server and all of them are connected to same cluster. Also i.e. web-site and chat server use same bucket.

If you need two different web apps to access one cluster you can create one bucket per app. Couchbase bucket is like "database" in RDBMS, and couchbase server (cluster) is like MySQL server: server can have many databases that can be accessed by different apps.